# MYSQL: Using a join after and AND

Tags: mysql, join

the MYSQL query below combines a number of tables. However, as you can see, I would like to add a LEFT JOIN at the end on the receipt table. The query returns an error when I add the LEFT JOIN. Anybody know the best way to LEFT JOIN the receipt table to the rest of the query. Sorry if this is a newbie question. Thanks !!

```
SELECT user_name, expense_category, merchant_name, expense_cost, expense_date, expense_status,    receipt_image, expense_comment
FROM users, expenses, merchants, receipts
WHERE ".$adminId." = expenses.admin_id
AND expenses.user_id = users.user_id
AND expenses.merchant_id = merchants.merchant_id
AND LEFT JOIN (receipts)
ON expenses.receipt_id = receipts.receipt_id
```

Comment: A left join clause is used on the FROM section. But to help you we need to know what table is left joining with this receipts table and what is the joining columns from both tables.

Comment: @Ullas Please stop making minor, insignificant edits to people's posts, that add code formatting to things that are not code. Code formatting should _not_ be used for emphasis, particularly not where no emphasis is called for in the first place. You have a very high rejected edit ratio and therefore risk to get yourself auto-banned from editing posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a clean approach of doing it, note that I have added alias for the tables for better readability so you may use the alias name in the select statement to fetch the column from the proper table.

```
SELECT 
u.user_name, 
ex.expense_category, 
mer.merchant_name, 
ex.expense_cost, 
ex.expense_date, 
ex.expense_status,
re.receipt_image, 
ex.expense_comment
FROM users u
JOIN expenses ex on ex.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN merchants mer on mer.merchant_id = ex.merchant_id
LEFT JOIN receipts re on re.receipt_id = ex.receipt_id
where
ex.admin_id = '$adminId'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT user_name, expense_category, merchant_name, expense_cost, expense_date, expense_status,    receipt_image, expense_comment
FROM users, expenses, merchants, receipts
LEFT JOIN receipts ON expenses.receipt_id = receipts.receipt_id
WHERE ".$adminId." = expenses.admin_id
AND expenses.user_id = users.user_id
AND expenses.merchant_id = merchants.merchant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join clauses instead of where clause. I.e.

```
SELECT user_name, expense_category, merchant_name, expense_cost, expense_date, expense_status,   receipt_image, expense_comment
FROM users
INNER JOIN expenses on users.user_id = expenses.expenses_id
INNER JOIN merchants on merchants.merchant_id = expenses.merchant_id
    LEFT JOIN (receipts)
ON expenses.receipt_id = receipts.receipt_id
WHERE ".$adminId." = expenses.admin_id
```

Note that any columns from the receipts will be NULL in the select statement whenever there's no matching record.

Comment: The answer from @Abhik is better, because it uses table aliases and ensures that your column names are unambiguous.